# Google Chrome 'ruined' after someone else logged in

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar, icons, bookmarks

Google Chrome was the default browser that came with my laptop.

I have a Google account which I was logged into Chrome with. Someone else logged into my chrome using their account which has resulted in everything being lost.

I logged in again to find my theme, bookmarks, history, most visited sites were gone and now instead of 'piling up' under the symbol already pinned to the Windows 7 task bar it opens a second symbol on the taskbar and 'piles up' under that instead which has never happened before. I have tried unpinning and repinning which didn't work.

I have tried syncing my account numerous times to no avail, I have searched high and low on the Chrome forums for any kind of answer. I have tried accessing that thing in documents to try and recover my bookmarks but I can't find them (I had hidden files enabled etc etc).

I really really want it back how it was as I had a lot of bookmarked sites and quick access to sites and everything was how i used it, and I hate that it now opens a new icon on the taskbar.

Comment: Has the other user created a new Chrome profile? http://www.labnol.org/software/create-family-profiles-in-google-chrome/4394/

Comment: He basically logged into his gmail account using the chrome login, I would really rather not have multiple users on my chrome as this seems to have been what caused the issue in the first place 
Thanks for such a prompt answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try Re-installing chrome and login again.

It seems that when you logged in after the other person, somehow your account synced with that state of chrome and every-time you login, the preferences used are the ones similar to the other user.